# How to map function to weight tensors of variable shapes in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to compute the loss for my nn. I have the number of layers coming in as an argument and am looking to compute loss similar to:

```
  loss = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=tf_train_labels, logits=logits) + 
      L2_beta * (tf.nn.l2_loss(weights_1) + tf.nn.l2_loss(weights_2))
  )
```

If I have the layers coming in as an argument, this rendition will not work. I could use a for loop to add up all the weight losses, but that's not elegant. I'd like to map `nn.l2_loss` to each element of list `weights`. But I cant get it to work!

```
import tensorflow as tf

weights = []
weights.append(tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([784, 1024])))
weights.append(tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1024, 512])))
weights.append(tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([512, 10])))

print(weights)

# this works
tf.nn.l2_loss(weights[0]) + tf.nn.l2_loss(weights[1]) + tf.nn.l2_loss(weights[2])

# this is what I need
tf.map_fn(tf.nn.l2_loss, weights)
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example below I just used the regular `map`. Don't have idea if this performs as good as `tf.map_fn`, but does the job without **for** loops.

```
import tensorflow as tf

weights = []
weights.append(tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([784, 1024])))
weights.append(tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1024, 512])))
weights.append(tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([512, 10])))
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

required=tf.nn.l2_loss(weights[0]) + tf.nn.l2_loss(weights[1]) + tf.nn.l2_loss(weights[2])    
required2=tf.reduce_sum(map(tf.nn.l2_loss,weights))

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init_op)
  your_result=sess.run(required)
  my_result=sess.run(required2)

print 'your res ::{}, My res ::{}'.format(your_result,my_result)
```

for python3 use instead :

```
required2=tf.reduce_sum(list(map(tf.nn.l2_loss,weights)))
```

Comment: I got this: `TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'map'> to Tensor. Contents: <map object at 0x000002C505578C50>. Consider casting elements to a supported type.`

Comment: I should mention I'm running python3

Comment: thanks! Am new to python and tensorflow and appreciate the help. Tried putting in `next` but it actually returned the wrong values in the result. You are both a gentleman and a scholar ty.

Comment: I should mention that in Python3, this worked for me:   
`required2=tf.reduce_sum(list(map(tf.nn.l2_loss, weights)))`

Comment: @Zafar , Thanks for the correction, I just forgot `tf.nn.l2_loss` is a function itself. We don't need a lambda function for the mapping. Will update my answer